# XSLT 1.0 multiple record to single record

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Below is my requirement ,

Input XML :

```
<ns0:TestDTM xmlns:ns0="http://SchemaIN">
  <ID>1234</ID>
  <Ref>A1</Ref>
  <Detail>
    <Qualifier>Q1</Qualifier>
    <Value>Name</Value>
  </Detail>
    <Detail>
    <Qualifier>Q2</Qualifier>
    <Value>Address</Value>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <Qualifier>Q3</Qualifier>
    <Value>AddressType</Value>
  </Detail>
</ns0:TestDTM>
```

Desired OutPut : Header Record will repeat only once

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://SchemaOUT">
  <Header>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Ref>A1</Ref>
    <Value1>Name</Value1>
    <Value2>Address</Value2>
    <Value3>AddressType</Value2>
  </Header>
</ns0:Root>
```

XSLT 1.0 Written :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://SchemaIN" xmlns:ns0="http://SchemaOUT">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:TestDTM" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:TestDTM">
    <ns0:Root>
      <xsl:for-each select="Detail">
        <Header>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Qualifier = 'Q1'">
              <Value1>
                <xsl:value-of select="Value/text()" />
              </Value1>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Qualifier = 'Q3'">
              <Value2>
                <xsl:value-of select="Value/text()" />
              </Value2>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </Header>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ns0:Root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT i have written is not giving the desired output. I need to use xslt 1.0 only.The header in the output repeats only once

Answer (score 0):

Try the following XSLT-1.0 code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://SchemaIN" xmlns:ns0="http://SchemaOUT"  exclude-result-prefixes="s0 msxsl">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />

  <xsl:template match="/s0:TestDTM">
    <ns0:Root>
      <Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail|ID|Ref" />
      </Header>
    </ns0:Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Detail">
    <xsl:element name="{concat('Value',substring(Qualifier,2,1))}">
      <xsl:value-of select="Value/text()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://SchemaOUT">
    <Header>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <Ref>A1</Ref>
        <Value1>Name</Value1>
        <Value2>Address</Value2>
        <Value3>AddressType</Value3>
    </Header>
</ns0:Root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution this works , this logic is one part of the xml and your answer works for it. I have updated the input XML and desired output. Does the same xslt also works for it ?

Comment: I added a template for handling other nodes. It removes the namespace. Without the namespace the solution could have been simpler.